# Как в письме удалить один атрибут? Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Необходимо из шаблона письма удалить один атрибут товара из двух, т.е. как на рисунке это атрибут - Статус.
шаблон письма в этих файлах:
`woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php`
`woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в 1м файле вызывается функция `wc_get_email_order_items`, которая подключает второй файл шаблона `woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php`, в котором в свою очередь вызывается функция `wc_display_item_meta`

```
    wc_display_item_meta(
        $item,
        array(
            'label_before' => '<strong class="wc-item-meta-label" style="float: ' . esc_attr( $text_align ) . '; margin-' . esc_attr( $margin_side ) . ': .25em; clear: both">',
        )
    );
```

$item я так понял это атрибут?

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить атрибут `Статус`,  а атрибут `Цвет` оставить?

Comment: $item - это order item, из него можно получить товар $item->get_product() или атрибуты $item->get_formatted_meta_data() и т.д.

Comment: @noname228, подскажите, вызвал я get_formatted_meta_data(), и как из полученных данных удалить атрибут? что-то не могу найти подходящий пример. Можете скинуть ссылку, где это можно посмотреть как удалить?

Comment: Функцию можно загуглить, но проще сделать обычный foreach и посмотреть что он выводит и сделать исключение, чтобы не выводить тот атрибут, который не нужен. Вот еще нашел хук, но не проверял https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684334/filter-out-unwanted-order-item-meta-data-from-woocommerce-email-notifications